# Positioning boxes in a box with backtracking in Java

Tags: java, backtracking, box-puzzle

A large cube-shaped box has the dimensions `5x5x5`. This box is to be completely filled with smaller boxes. Possible candidates are:

- `1x1x1`, 5-fold
- `1x2x4`, 6-fold
- `2x2x3`, 6-fold

An additional "magic" box with the dimensions `1x1x1` should always be placed in the middle/center of the large box.

This should be solved with backtracking in Java.

My attempt works correctly (i hope), but for example `n=2`,... and `n=20` the algorithm don't stops. I am looking for a way to improve it. Thanks.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Box {
    final int len = 5;
    final int empty = -1;
    final int max;
    int[][][] solution = new int[len][len][len];
    int[][] candidates = {
            {2, 2, 3},
            {1, 2, 4},
            {1, 1, 1},
    };
    int[] taken = new int[candidates.length];
    int freeSpace = len * len * len;

    Box(final int max, final boolean withMagicCuboid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
                    solution[i][j][k] = empty;
                }
            }
        }

        this.max = max;
        if (withMagicCuboid) {
            // insert magic cuboid
            solution[2][2][2] = 2;
            taken[2]++;
            freeSpace--;
        }

        solve(0, 0);
    }

    boolean insert(final int c, final int x, final int y, final int z, final int dir) {
        if (taken[c] >= max) {
            return false;
        }
        int[] a = candidates[c];
        for (int i = 0; i < a[0]; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[1]; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < a[2]; k++) {
                    int x2 = x;
                    int y2 = y;
                    int z2 = z;
                    if (dir == 0) {
                        x2 += i;
                        y2 += j;
                        z2 += k;
                    }
                    if (dir == 1) {
                        x2 += i;
                        y2 += k;
                        z2 += j;
                    }
                    if (dir == 2) {
                        x2 += j;
                        y2 += i;
                        z2 += k;
                    }
                    if (dir == 3) {
                        x2 += j;
                        y2 += k;
                        z2 += i;
                    }
                    if (dir == 4) {
                        x2 += k;
                        y2 += i;
                        z2 += j;
                    }
                    if (dir == 5) {
                        x2 += k;
                        y2 += j;
                        z2 += i;
                    }
                    if (x2 < 0 || x2 >= len || y2 < 0 || y2 >= len || z2 < 0 || z2 >= len) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (solution[x2][y2][z2] != empty) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a[0]; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[1]; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < a[2]; k++) {
                    int x2 = x;
                    int y2 = y;
                    int z2 = z;
                    if (dir == 0) {
                        x2 += i;
                        y2 += j;
                        z2 += k;
                    }
                    if (dir == 1) {
                        x2 += i;
                        y2 += k;
                        z2 += j;
                    }
                    if (dir == 2) {
                        x2 += j;
                        y2 += i;
                        z2 += k;
                    }
                    if (dir == 3) {
                        x2 += j;
                        y2 += k;
                        z2 += i;
                    }
                    if (dir == 4) {
                        x2 += k;
                        y2 += i;
                        z2 += j;
                    }
                    if (dir == 5) {
                        x2 += k;
                        y2 += j;
                        z2 += i;
                    }
                    solution[x2][y2][z2] = c;
                    freeSpace--;
                }
            }
        }
        taken[c]++;
        return true;
    }

    void remove(final int c, final int x, final int y, final int z, final int dir) {
        int[] a = candidates[c];
        for (int i = 0; i < a[0]; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[1]; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < a[2]; k++) {
                    int x2 = x;
                    int y2 = y;
                    int z2 = z;
                    if (dir == 0) {
                        x2 += i;
                        y2 += j;
                        z2 += k;
                    }
                    if (dir == 1) {
                        x2 += i;
                        y2 += k;
                        z2 += j;
                    }
                    if (dir == 2) {
                        x2 += j;
                        y2 += i;
                        z2 += k;
                    }
                    if (dir == 3) {
                        x2 += j;
                        y2 += k;
                        z2 += i;
                    }
                    if (dir == 4) {
                        x2 += k;
                        y2 += i;
                        z2 += j;
                    }
                    if (dir == 5) {
                        x2 += k;
                        y2 += j;
                        z2 += i;
                    }
                    solution[x2][y2][z2] = empty;
                    freeSpace++;
                }
            }
        }
        taken[c]--;
    }

    boolean isSolution() {
        return freeSpace <= 0;
    }

    boolean hasSolution() {
        return freeSpace > 0;
    }

    boolean solve(final int c, final int n) {
        if (c >= candidates.length || n >= max || !hasSolution()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
                    if (c == 2) {
                        // take a abbreviation
                        if (insert(c, i, j, k, 0)) {
                            if (isSolution()) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            if (hasSolution() && (solve(c, n + 1) || solve(c + 1, 0))) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            remove(c, i, j, k, 0);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // take all directions
                        for (int d = 0; d < 6; d++) {
                            if (insert(c, i, j, k, d)) {
                                if (isSolution()) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                if (hasSolution() && (solve(c, n + 1) || solve(c + 1, 0))) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                remove(c, i, j, k, d);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        for (int n = 25; n >= 21; n--) {
            System.out.println("n = " + n);
            Box box = new Box(n, true);
            System.out.println(box.isSolution());
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(box.taken));
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(box.solution));
        }
        // The problematic cases:
        {
            int n = 20;
            System.out.println("n = " + n);
            Box box = new Box(n, true);
            System.out.println(box.isSolution());
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(box.taken));
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(box.solution));
        }
        for (int n = 1; n <= 6; n++) {
            System.out.println("n = " + n);
            Box box = new Box(n, true);
            System.out.println(box.isSolution());
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(box.taken));
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(box.solution));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## simple constructor

In my opinion this ctor is doing too much:

```
    Box( ... ) {
        ...
        solve(0, 0);
    }
```

The class invariant appears to be: "We always have a valid solved cube."
Or put another way, there is *no* invariant we can reason about
for most of this code, because it executes prior to completion of the ctor.
Worse, `solve` could potentially return False, which we ignore,
so caller could get almost anything back.

Just leave the final `solve` call out, let the caller worry about that.
Having an unsolved instance that unit tests can pass around
can be very helpful during initial development.

Then you'd be able to add automated
[unit tests](https://junit.org/junit5)
to this submission.

---

## problem statement

> An additional "magic" box with the dimensions 1x1x1 ...

```
        if (withMagicCuboid) {
            ...
            taken[2]++;
```

My interpretation of the problem is we're free to place five tiny cubes
anywhere we want, and the magic one is a sixth cube with constrained position.
So I wouldn't bump the `taken` count here.

---

## meaningful identifiers

The constructor accepts a `max` parameter,
which could be a fine name.
But you really need to `/** tell us */` what it means.

```
    boolean solve(final int c, final int n) {
```

That is the wrong signature to offer a reviewer.
Both numbers are super important,
and you haven't told a reviewer how to interpret them, what they mean.
You absolutely positively need to add at least
one sentence of `/** javadoc */` to this method.

Consider renaming `c` to some longer abbreviation or perhaps
go all the way to `candidate`.

Perhaps `n` describes our current `level` within the search tree?

```
                    if (c == 2) {
                        // take a abbreviation
```

It's unclear why we need to special case this.
Explaining **why** would be a helpful comment.
Maybe it's a symmetry argument?
Which leaves me wondering if other candidates exhibit relevant symmetries.

Rather than a hardcoded magic index of "candidate number two" here,
you might prefer to special case on "volume == 1".

```
                        // take all directions
```

Thank you for helpfully pointing out that `d` denotes "direction".
Consider renaming to `dir`.

Aha! I see you did that down in `insert`.
May as well do it up in the caller, as well.

Defining `hasSolution` to be `not isSolution` is
[surprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).
Consider renaming to `isNotSolved`, `isUnsolved`, or `isSolvable`.

---

## linear algebra

Yikes! This is tedious.

```
                    if (dir == 0) {
                    ...
                    if (dir == 1) {
                    ...
                    if (dir == 2) {
                    ...
                    if (dir == 3) {
                    ...
                    if (dir == 4) {
                    ...
                    if (dir == 5) {
```

We see `3!` permuations of the `3` coordinate axes.
Representing direction as a single small integer turned out to be inconvenient.

An alternative representation would show it as
a unit vector pointing along one of the axes:

```
            {0, 0, 1},
            {0, 1, 0},
            {1, 0, 0},
```

perhaps with another three pointing in the negative direction, or more cleanly
by using a ±1 coefficient to show we're going the other way.

Alternatively you might list the three (or six) cases
with permutations of `{0, 1, 2}` axis indices instead of permuting `{i, j, k}` variables.

```
                    if (dir == 0) {
                    ...
                    if (dir == 1) {
                    ...
                    if (dir == 2) {
                    ...
                    if (dir == 3) {
                    ...
                    if (dir == 4) {
                    ...
                    if (dir == 5) {
```

zomg we're doing it *again*?!?

It seems pretty clear that we really want a helper here,
which accepts a 3-space `Point` plus a direction,
and returns the desired `{x2, y2, z2}` Point.

`remove` would use the same helper,
so it's no longer copy-pasta taken from `insert`.

---

## single responsibility

`insert` does two things:

- check whether candidate in given orientation will fit *at all*
- place the candidate

Break out at least one helper to reflect that.

---

## debugability

```
                    solution[x2][y2][z2] = c;
```

Certainly this is *correct*.
It doesn't seem very convenient.
*Any* value besides `empty` would do.

Suppose `solve` returns a solution to your colleague,
or to a unit test. Each of them is playing the role of Verifier.
Why should the Verifier believe the solution is accurate?
Both verification and graphical display would be much easier
if we wrote a distinct value for each piece placed.

We could associate 18 indexes with our six + six + six pieces.
Or we could use (candidateType, candidateSerialNumber) tuples.
Alternate representations of a tuple include array of complex numbers,
and array of floats where integer portion denotes serial number and
decimal fraction denotes type.

---

## algorithm

Consider choosing a random candidate oriented in a random direction
at each step.

It would be helpful to be able to prove theorems about a puzzle in progress.
For example, if an empty slab will require `1 x ...` pieces to fill it,
and its volume exceeds total volume of such pieces that remain,
then we know it's time to backtrack.

Keeping track of occupancy, the fraction full, at each of five layers
may help prioritize using appropriate piece.
Early on we see low occupancy and anything goes.
With more pieces placed, it becomes increasingly
important that a placed piece should *exactly fit*
so it goes all the way to the 5x5x5 boundary.

"Volume remaining", the empty volume, would be an admissible heuristic for
[A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) search.

---

This code achieves many of its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: Thanks for your review. *"I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it."* I'm relatively new here and don't know exactly what to do, but the code is not protected (from my side), feel free to use it. :)

Comment: It's sort of a boiler plate summary response. The purpose of submitting a git feature branch to [PR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control#Pull_requests) review is to answer a pair of questions: (1.) Is it correct? (Is it _obviously_ correct? Is it too tricky so we don't know if it's correct? Did we happen to notice a bug? Do docstrings and unit tests instill confidence in correctness?), and also (2.) Is it maintainable? (The team is going to be responsible for fixing it. _Could_ we fix it?) I was answering "yes" and "yes" to those questions. I could delegate to junior devs

Comment: *"My interpretation of the problem is we're free to place five tiny cubes anywhere we want, and the magic one is a sixth cube with constrained position"* that's the correct meaning, btw. After the constrained cube is placed, there are still five cubes left.

Comment: Oh, pardon me, quite right. The aspects are slightly scattered through the code. At that point I had not yet read the (uniform across piece types) `if (taken[c] >= max)` test. I was anticipating the `{5, 6, 6}` counts from the problem description would appear in some other piece of code. Wrong assumption, whoops.

Comment: It might make sense to initialize this array with {5,6,6}... and then count backwards.

Comment: the source is now [here](https://github.com/tgrothe/box-puzzle).